# how to trigger jquery parent.on() method on first click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, parent-child

I am working on a jquery script that involves closing a bootstrap modal and then opening another. The flow is that first the user is asked for mobile number and then an ajax call is  to backend and upon a success next bootstrap modal is shown. If I click `$('#otp-close)` nothing happens at first click and on second click, it is closing the opened modal and then opening the new modal as expected. Code is as follows.

```
$('#otp-close').click(function(e){
    console.log('first click');
    $('#login-modal1').attr('style',"display:block !important;");
    $('#login-modal1').removeClass("modal fade").addClass("modal fade right in");
    $('#phone').val('');
    $('#login-modal1').parent().on('show.bs.modal', function (e) { 
        $('#login-modal2').modal('hide');
        });
        });
```

`I have already tried all the methods like modal.hide(), modal('hide') and modal.show(), modal.('show')`. The aforementioned methods didnt work for me. I think the issue is with some custom JS files and I tried the code posted here since custom JS is needed for the page to work. Following are my bootstrap modals.

```
<div class="modal fade" data-dismiss="modal" id="login-modal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="loginmodal-container phone-number-screen" id="phoneno-screen">
        <div class="close-icon"><a href="#" data-rel="back" id="phone-close" ><img src="{% static 'images/close-icon.png' %}"></a></div>
        <div class="login-logo">
            <a href="#"><img src="{% static 'images/logo.png' %}"></a>
        </div>
        <h3>Type your phone number</h3>
        <form id="phone_login_form" method="get" action="{% url 'accounts:makeotp' %}">{% csrf_token %}
            <div class="phone-number-field">
                <input type="text" name="phone" id="post-code" value="+91" />
                <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="" maxlength="10" />
                <span id="errmsg_phone"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="phone-submit-button">
                <a href="#" id="phone-number-submit" disabled></a>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div class="privacy-link">
            <ul>
            <span><a href="#">Terms & Conditions</a></span>
            <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="modal fade" data-dismiss="modal" id="login-modal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
<div class="modal-dialog">


<div class="modal fade" data-dismiss="modal" id="login-modal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="loginmodal-container phone-number-screen" id="otp-screen">
        <div class="back-icon">
            <a class="close-icon" id="otp-close" href="#phoneno-screen" data-rel="back" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login-modal1" data-direction="right"><img src="{% static 'images/go-back.png' %}"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="login-logo">
            <a href="#"><img src="{% static 'images/logo.png' %}"></a>
        </div>
        <h3>Enter Verification Code</h3>
        <form action="{% url 'accounts:verifyotp' %}" id="otp_form" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
            <div class="phone-number-field">
                <input type="text" name="phone" class="otp" value="" maxlength="1" />
                <input type="text" name="phone" class="otp" value="" maxlength="1" />
                <input type="text" name="phone" class="otp" value="" maxlength="1" />
                <input type="text" name="phone" class="otp" value="" maxlength="1" />
                <span id="errmsg_otp"></span>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="sign-up" value="Sign Up" disabled />
            </div>
            <a href="#" id="resend_otp" class="resend-otp-link">Resend Verification Code?</a>
        </form>
        <div class="privacy-link">
            <ul>
            <span><a href="#">Terms & Conditions</a></span>
            <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please note that I went on with this strange approach since no default or convenient ways worked for me.

TIA

Comment: Did you try just chaining on `.trigger('show.bs.modal')`  ?

Comment: Why are you binding `show.bs.modal` event inside `click` event?

Comment: Thanks for teh quick update, but @A.Wolff, As I mentioned in question no conventional methods worked for me. adeneo it would be helpful if you mention how to do chaining with existing script.

Comment: I tried chaining, but that didnt hide existing modal :(